# Adding to hist()-like bars in plot()

Tags: r, plot, histogram, distribution, bar-chart

I would like to add a histogram of a distribution of a variable on an already generated `plot()` window. This script is heavily customized and I can only add to it. I can't use `hist()` to plot. X-axis is on an continuous scale, Y-scale is probability [0,1] (**edit:** One of the y-axis is probability the other is continuous). How can I add bars to represent the distribution of this variable on the already generated `plot()`? Base-R only please

What I have done so far is `plot()` and then do the distribution with `lines(hist()$breaks, hist()$density, type="h")` which however gives me only lines but not the box-like bars of `hist()`

From what I understand `boxplot()` won't help and `barplot()` requires factors not continuous scale variables (like I have).

**UPDATE:** The `hist(...,add=T)` option does not work for me. I would like to be as flexible as with in the `line()` solution (thus able to transform x and y vectors), but instead of lines to draw boxes. Any ideas?

Comment: trying to re-read the title of your question over and over again, I think there must be some error in the English... don't know how to correct it though.

Comment: "Add a histogram to an existing plot window"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add the `hist()` plot to already existing plot using `add = TRUE`. Don't forget to use `freq = FALSE` to say you want the probability scale, not the count scale.

```
set.seed(123)
x<-rnorm(100)

plot(x, exp(x)/(1+exp(x)), col = "green") # some plot
hist(x, freq = FALSE, add = TRUE)
```

**EDIT:** If you need to perform any manipulation on the computed histogram, you can replace the `hist` call by splitting it into computation and the plotting itself, which is done using `rect()` (see the [source code of `plot.histogram`](http://www1.maths.lth.se/help/R/plot.histogram/)):

```
h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE) # computation
rect(h$breaks[-length(h$breaks)], 0, h$breaks[-1], h$intensities) # plotting
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't quite work because of the custom y-axis limits (which I cannot change) check with `x<-rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=5)`. How does `hist()` actually plot the "boxes"?

Comment: @ECII, good question. `hist()` actually plots the boxes using the `rect()` function. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your idea with `lines()` could work but then you have to use `mids` instead of breaks for `x` values and also make your lines wider with argument `lwd=`. Argument `lend="butt"` will ensure that lines are not rounded.

```
set.seed(123)
x<-rnorm(100)
zz<-hist(x)

plot(x=c(-2.5,2.5),y=c(0,1),type="n")
lines(zz$mids, zz$density, type="h",lwd=50,lend="butt")
```

[image]

### Update

To get something like boxes (as those are lines you can't change just fill of them) you can plot two lines above each other with different colors and different width, and change all density values by small amount.

```
plot(x=c(-2.5,2.5),y=c(0,1),type="n")
lines(zz$mids, zz$density, type="h",lwd=50,lend="butt")
lines(zz$mids, zz$density-0.005, type="h",lwd=48,lend="butt",col="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `$mid` tip(+1). Is there any way to draw boxes instead of  lines of `lwd=50`?

Comment: Nice, but note that `hist` is actually using `rect`, not `lines`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `lines` on the object returned by `hist`:

```
h <- hist(..., plot=FALSE)
# Other plotting functions go here.
lines(h) # will now plot the histogram in the plotting window.
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use this. Check my comment to Thomas's answer

Comment: I've read through the updates and comments, but I'm confused why `hist`'s use of `rect` is a problem?